# Как легко определить винительный падеж?

Tags: орфография, падежи

Как отличать винительный от именительного?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В контексте. В именительном падеже всегда стоит подлежащее, а в винительном - дополнение. Кроме того, если нужно слово одинаково звучит на именительном и винительном падежах, замените его мысленно на другое, которое звучит по-разному, например, неа слово "улица", и посмотрите, будет ли оно отвечать на вопрос "кого-что?" и изменится ли оно на "улицу".

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае,конечно,лучше воспользоваться подстановкой тех существительных,которые имеют различные грамматические формы в Им. и Вин.падежах.Для существительных первого склонения-"земля","землю";для существительных второго склонения-"конь","коня".Легко запомнить эти слова можно в предложении-"Конь по земле бежит."

Answer (score 0):

к слову в именит. падеже задаем двойной вопрос"есть кто?-что?", а к слову в винительном - "вижу кого?-что?"

Answer (score 0):

Детям нравится такой способ: подставляем слово "Корова". Не изменилось? - Им. п.
Изменилось (корову) - винительный. Т.е. подставляем одушевленное существительное. Именно у них и не совпадает им. и вин. падежи.